# How to perform push operation in a nested Immutable.js Map and Lists.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, immutable.js

I'm using pepperoni-app-kit for react-native that comes with Immutable.js. I have never used Immutable.js before and I find to really hard to perform a simple task

I want to push a message in message List, which is inside a Map.

`someReducer.js`

```
import {Map,List} from 'immutable';

const initialState = Map({isReady : false , messages : List([])});

// reducer switch case
return state.update('messages',messages=>messages.concat(action.Message.payloadString);
// not working
//I also tried
return state.get('messages').push(Immutable.Map({text:'some text',...}))
```

How to write this ES6 code with Immutable.js

```
var newState = state; // copy state 
newState.messages.push({text:'hello world',...otherInfo}); // make changes
return object.assign({},newState); // return a new object.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in immutablejs, how to push a new data to a Map which value is an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648907/in-immutablejs-how-to-push-a-new-data-to-a-map-which-value-is-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
describe('how-to-perform-push-operation-in-a-nested-immutable-js-map-and-lists', () => {
    const initialState = Immutable.Map({
        isReady: false, 
        messages: Immutable.List([]),
    });

    it('should `push` using List.update', () => {
        const payload = 'some text';
        const updatedState = initialState.update('messages',
            (list) => (list.push(payload))
        );
        // passes:
        expect(updatedState.getIn(['messages', 0])).to.equal(payload);
    });

    it('should `concat` using List.update', () => {
        const multiMessagePayload = ['alpha', 'beta'];
        const reUpdatedState = initialState.update('messages',
            (list) => (list.concat(multiMessagePayload))
        );
        // passes:
        expect(reUpdatedState.get('messages').size).to.equal(2);
    });
});
```